# Models trained with TensorFlow are not available in Django

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

Key bias_1 not found in checkpoint
     [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at Programing\web_programing\django\django-vegiter\predict\views.py:20) ]]

Trace Back

```
saver.restore(sess, save_path) 
…
err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing")
```

Run in Python virtual environment

Django               2.2.5
Keras-Applications   1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing  1.1.0
numpy                1.17.1
pandas               0.25.1
tensorboard          1.14.0
tensorflow           1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator 1.14.0
termcolor            1.1.0

## Create your views here.

def index(request):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 4])
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="bias")

hypothesis = tf.matmul(X, W) + b

saver = tf.train.Saver()
model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(model)
save_path = "./model/saved.cpkt"
saver.restore(sess, save_path)

if request.method == "POST":
    avg_temp = float(request.POST['avg_temp'])
    min_temp = float(request.POST['min_temp'])
    max_temp = float(request.POST['max_temp'])
    rain_fall = float(request.POST['rain_fall'])

    price = 0

    data = ((avg_temp, min_temp, max_temp, rain_fall), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    arr = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)

    x_data = arr[0:4]
    dict = sess.run(hypothesis, feed_dict={X: x_data})

    price = dict[0]
else:
    price = 0
return render(request, 'predict/index.html', {'price': price})
```

POST

Variable        Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken  'BeE48x03YbOY3tIC7eF8L0tKrZME'
avg_temp         '24'
min_temp         '12'
max_temp         '31'
rain_fall        '0.9'

After receiving the post data, we want the price variable to have a forecast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concept**

At high level we can thing of graph as mathematical expression like (x+3x^2-.6x^3) which defines operation to be performed on a variable x. On the other hand session is where value of x and all the intermediate values like "3x^2" etc are stored.

To restore session we need graph same elements for which session is saved.

When you are running code below

```py
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([4, 1]), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name="bias")
```

Tensorflow will create the variable and add that to default graph which may not have same structure as the saved graph.

**Steps to Restore Both Graph and Session**

- Restore graph from ".meta" file first
- Then you can get reference of tensors and operations from the graphs by using graph.get_tensor_by_name()/graph.get_operation_by_name()
- Then you can do some addition to the graph, that won't affect session restoration
- do variable initialization before restoring the session. If you do it latter it will overwrite the restored variables
- restore the session from checkpoint

**Code will look like below**

```py
## restore the graph
importer = tf.train.import_meta_graph("%s.meta"%saved_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

## get reference of output of tensor and set it to variable
## here ":0" indicates the output of an operation
W = graph.get_tensor_by_name("weights")
output = graph.get_tensor_by_name("hidden5_out:0")


## restore the variables in session
session = tf.Session(graph=graph)
importer.restore(session, saved_path)
```